# Como enviar parâmetro para ActionResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho a `ActionResult Login` que valida meu usuário e salva os dados em uma Session, caso tudo dê ok, redireciona para a `ActionResult BPAC`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string pUsuario, string pSenha)
{
    oUsuario = modelOff.usuarios.SingleOrDefault(p => p.usuario1 == pUsuario && p.senha == pSenha);

    if (oUsuario == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ErroLogin");
    }
    else
    {
        Session["usuario"] = oUsuario;
        return RedirectToAction("BPAC");
    }
}
```

A `ActionResult BPAC` precisa de uma `string` chamada `ibge` para funcionar, e eu tenho que pegar a mesma na `Session` criada anteriormente, porém o sistema não a reconhece.

```
public ActionResult BPAC()
{
    if (Session["usuario"] == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ErroLogin");
    }
    string ibge = Session["usuario"].ibge; //<<<<< ERRO AQUI
    List<Estabelecimento> listaEstabelecimento = new Estabelecimento().listaEstabelecimento(ibge);
    return View(listaEstabelecimento);
}
```

Essa linha que marquei não é reconhecida pelo sistema. Como eu faço pra usar a `Session` aqui no meu `Controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use o RedirectToAction passando os parâmetros.

```
return RedirectToAction("BPAC", new { pUsuario = "admin", pSenha = "xpto" });
```

e coloque os parâmetros no action

```
public ActionResult BPAC(string pUsuario, string pSenha)
```

Comment: Irei precisar dos dados da `Session` em outros `Views`, como fazer pra pegar através da `Session`?

Comment: use ViewBag. Ex. ViewBag.Usuario e ViewBag.Senha